# Stream audio from web browser

Tags: audio, streaming

Is it possible to capture all audio stream on my PC (from web browser) and stream it via LAN ?

I use Yandex Music (music.yandex.ru) service. So I logged into my yandex account and I have no any audio files, just online stream. I want to make something like LAN-radio. Users will visit an HTML-page located on our server and listen my audio stream.

Can I use icecast or similar software to stream non-file audio?
Or should I connect my PC's line out to line IN (or mic) and read audio stream via Java or flash? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at things like Jack and Soundflower? These allow you to reroute the audio from one program to another. You could then reroute the sound into Java or flash and go from there.

https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/

http://jackaudio.org/

Comment: Yes. I deal with qjackctl but I can not capture audio with it.
Now I have googled and found pretty simple solution. It is arecord command.
I use something like `arecord -c 2 -f S16_LE -r 44100 -t raw | lame -r - out.mp3` but quality is horrible

Comment: You'll probably always have some loss in quality. Especially if you're saving your file as an mp3. Think about the quality loss of a picture as its gradually passed around online. 

One thing that springs to mind though looking at your arecord command is that the sampling rate is always set to 44100. It's very likely that the sounds you're streaming can have higher or lower sampling rates.
That is weird that you're not able to capture audio using qjackctl. I've always avoided Jack though. Soundflower is a lot better in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`WebRTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API) and [`MediaStream API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API) for that. You can get audio from user's audio device or a stream they are playing in browser. You can find dcoumentation on those APIs from MDN pages.